# AC Input for 48 Volt DC Powered Server

Tags: hardware

I bought a Rackable Systems PSCH-SR/IDE off of eBay not realizing it has a 48V DC power requirement.  Is there any way to replace the power supply, or connect up an inverter of some kind?

I understand these were designed to go into big data centers with DC power on tap.  Guess I should have looked twice as the price seemed to good to be true!

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion, put it back on e-bay :) However, if you feel comfortable using it as a hobby / test server in your home or office, you should be able to get a clean enough 48v power supply from any electronics supply store. Just check the pin out on the server to make sure you're connecting it properly.

Really, though, I'd just put it back on e-bay and chalk it up to an (expensive) lesson learned.

Comment: Cool thanks, I'll try that.  It's just a hobby box, so hopefully I can still come out ahead w/ some kind of frankenstein thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could always go back to eBay and hunt down a power supply.  48V DC is a telco standard, so there may be more equipment hanging around out there.

Answer (score 0):

no need to worry.

just find out what 'thing' actually need this power?
is it a fan or lamp or what....

and you can just replace whatever that fan/lamp/thing with other fan/lamp/thing with ac power supply and it will just work.

Comment: The "thing" is the entire server, and so replacement isn't really viable. =)

Comment: ok then...
you could just buy any laptop or any other adaptor with the same output.
or ask some electrical store engineer to built one for you.
it would be easy