# SGI Rackable Systems server, what type of power connector

Tags: electrical-power, adapter

I purchased a used "Rackable Systems" server off eBay and I discovered to my surprise when it arrived it has power connectors which appear to require ~48 volts DC input.  It looks like this:

[image: connectors]

[image: connectors close up]

What sort of adapter is normally used to plug this into regular 110v AC power (normal "wall plug" power in the United States)?

EDIT:

My question is specifically what is this power connector called? - different from [AC Input for 48 Volt DC Powered Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/76540/ac-input-for-48-volt-dc-powered-server) which is asking how to hook it up (a question which was never answered with anything other than, essentially, "get a new server").

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AC Input for 48 Volt DC Powered Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/76540/ac-input-for-48-volt-dc-powered-server)

Comment: @JohnMahowald Thanks, however it doesn't look like anyone directly answered that question either.  There are various sources of raw 48v power but I'm looking for, ideally, a link to something I can just buy that has regular power (NEMA 5-15 grounded (Type B)) on one side, and the plug in the photo on the other side.  I find it hard to believe that no such conversion device exists (not that anyone has said that, but I haven't encountered anything yet - I will post if I find it)

Comment: Does anyone even know what this connector is called?

Comment: I've been googling around a lot and can't find anything.  There seem to be some (most?) versions of this type of PSU that have only 3 connections, which makes more sense: + - and ground.  And when I've come across just the PSU for sale, there are pics where you can see that there are only 3 connections, so if you could find the connector, it'd be easy enough to wire it up (assuming you can also get a 48VDC source).

Comment: Best suggestion, go to the EE.SE Chat and ask there if someone knows what the connector or type is called.  I'm not sure it'd be ontopic to ask on EE.SE, but it might be.

Comment: Thanks @Ward, I’ll give that a shot. It also looks like there are replacement power supplies that fit this case, are reasonably priced, and that use normal 110v AC power, that’s probably the route I’ll go.  If it pans out I’ll post an answer with what part ended up working.

Answer (score 0):

Rackable had a product line involving custom servers and server racks with hot-plug power and network connections on a central bus. This may be one of them, and if so this connector may be unique to these racks.

Rackable bought the remnants of SGI in 2009 and changed their name then, so if this was sold under the Rackable name it's pretty old. This also makes it hard to google Rackable any more, as the pages under that name age out.